# Where we should specify font-size and list-style in ul and ol? for performance

Tags: css

Where we should specify font-size and list-stlye in ul and ol?

**#1** When we define font size for

nav ul li a {}

then

Where we should define

```
color
font-size
font-family
```

for `nav` or `ul` or `li` or `a`

---

**#2** and where we should define list-style

for `ul` or for `li`

**Edit:**

I think this will be efficient http://css-tricks.com/6386-efficiently-rendering-css/

```
nav {
font-size
font-family}

a {color:#ccc}

ul {list-style}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1st part:** Only thing you need to put into `a` is color. Because otherwise browser takes control of that.

**2nd part:** Doesnt really matter if its `ul` or `ol` or `li`

Comment: I thought specificity all possible things on <a> would be faster because because browser read right to left http://css-tricks.com/6386-efficiently-rendering-css/

Comment: I'm gonna have to test a bit more. Doesnt seem to be big difference though.

Comment: @JitendraVyas Even with the scale that i did it with, there didnt seem to be any significant differences if its in the outermost or the innermost element. ( as far as `li a` and `ul` goes )

Comment: I'm using HTML5 `nav` element

Comment: Right :P It is so common to use `nav` or `menu`as the `id` that i really just thought that you had a typo there and didnt include `#` ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can define all text variables anywhere within that list, starting at body and cascading down to the  tag. Each of those elements can be modified is css.

You can set the style of a list in the parent div. So, in the example you were asking about... the  is where you should define the list-style.